# Efficient Method for Solving system of mentioned odes?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I have applied rk-4 method on the following given system of odes found the numerical solution but accuracy is so much good. I converted the given system in $Ax=b$ form and then applied rk methods. Can any body tell me other methods with better accuracy than rk methods? Initial condition is also simple like given odes.
$$\begin{alignedat}{1}
\dot A_2(t)&=~~50A_5(t)&+42A_4(t)&+15A_3(t)&-125A_2(t) \\ 
\dot A_3(t)&=-190A_5(t)&-126A_4(t)&-63A_3(t)&+264A_2(t) \\ 
\dot A_4(t)&=~~360A_5(t)&+216A_4(t)&+108A_3(t)&-252A_2(t) \\ 
\dot A_5(t)&=-216A_5(t)&-\frac{648}{5}A_4(t)&-\frac{324}{5}A_3(t)&+\frac{432}{5}A_2(t) \end{alignedat}\\ 
A_2(0)=2.103802008, ~ A_3(0)=-9.002681798, ~ A_4(0)=15.14760370, ~ A_5(0)=-9.080420235
 $$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Darweesh ICS added

Comment: @Community
Actually I am solving Heat equation. For this purpose i applied polynomials to the heat equation and further convert the problem into system of odes. Now i need to solve system of odes with initial condition. Number of odes in the system is increasing with increasing of polynomials. I have applied rk-4 method but accuracy is not so much good.

Comment: you can calculate the eigenvalues value and eigenvectors by MATLAB and then you find the exact solution.

Comment: @Darweesh
Does it work on nonlinear system of odes?

Answer (score 1):

We can find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors and have

$$A(t) = c_1 e^{\lambda_1 t} v_1 + c_2 e^{\lambda_2 t} v_2 + c_3 e^{\lambda_3 t} v_3 + c_4 e^{\lambda_4 t} v_4$$

The eigenvalues / eigenvectors are

$\lambda_1 = \dfrac{1}{2} (-9) \left(\sqrt{33}+15\right), v_1 = \left\{\dfrac{1}{144} (-5) \left(\sqrt{33}+15\right),\dfrac{5}{216} \left(\sqrt{33}+87\right),-\dfrac{5}{2},1\right\}$

$\lambda_2 = \frac{1}{2} \left(-\sqrt{1081}-53\right), v_2 = \left\{-\dfrac{5 \left(167 \sqrt{1081}+13171\right)}{432 \left(13 \sqrt{1081}+257\right)},-\dfrac{10 \left(7 \sqrt{1081}-1357\right)}{9 \left(13 \sqrt{1081}+257\right)},-\dfrac{5 \left(37 \sqrt{1081}+2825\right)}{12 \left(13 \sqrt{1081}+257\right)},1\right\}$

$\lambda_3 = \dfrac{9}{2} \left(\sqrt{33}-15\right), v_3 = \left\{\dfrac{5}{144} \left(\sqrt{33}-15\right),\frac{1}{216} (-5) \left(\sqrt{33}-87\right),-\dfrac{5}{2},1\right\}$

$\lambda_4 = \dfrac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{1081}-53\right), v_4 \left\{-\dfrac{5 \left(\sqrt{1081}-53\right) \left(5 \sqrt{1081}+599\right)}{864 \left(13 \sqrt{1081}-257\right)},-\dfrac{10 \left(7 \sqrt{1081}+1357\right)}{9 \left(13 \sqrt{1081}-257\right)},-\dfrac{5 \left(37 \sqrt{1081}-2825\right)}{12 \left(13 \sqrt{1081}-257\right)},1\right\}$

Solving for the constants, we arrive at

$A(t) = \begin{pmatrix}-79.4328 e^{\frac{9}{2} \left(\sqrt{33}-15\right) t}+0.593282 e^{\frac{1}{2} (-9) \left(\sqrt{33}+15\right) t}+80.7346 e^{\frac{1}{2} \left(-\sqrt{1081}-53\right) t}+0.208652 e^{\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{1081}-53\right) t}\\464.905 e^{\frac{9}{2} \left(\sqrt{33}-15\right) t}-1.76829 e^{\frac{1}{2} (-9) \left(\sqrt{33}+15\right) t}-468. e^{\frac{1}{2} \left(-\sqrt{1081}-53\right) t}-4.13937 e^{\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{1081}-53\right) t}\\-617.924 e^{\frac{9}{2} \left(\sqrt{33}-15\right) t}+2.05916 e^{\frac{1}{2} (-9) \left(\sqrt{33}+15\right) t}+629.439 e^{\frac{1}{2} \left(-\sqrt{1081}-53\right) t}+1.57314 e^{\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{1081}-53\right) t}\\247.17 e^{\frac{9}{2} \left(\sqrt{33}-15\right) t}-0.823662 e^{\frac{1}{2} (-9) \left(\sqrt{33}+15\right) t}-255.826 e^{\frac{1}{2} \left(-\sqrt{1081}-53\right) t}+0.400021 e^{\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{1081}-53\right) t}\end{pmatrix}$

Compare that to your results by plotting each $A_i$.

Comment: Dose it work for nonlinear system of odes?

Comment: Yes, both RK4 and the method above work. Please see the answer by @LutzLehmann (+1) regarding why you are likely seeing your answers for the RK4 approach. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

As the largest eigenvalue, see the other answer by Moo, is about $λ_1\approx -100$, the stability condition for RK4 gives that somewhat correct results are only obtained for $100h\le 2.5$, or $h\le 0.025$. Useful results start with $h=5·10^{-3}$ and optimal RK4 results in double floats are obtained for $100h\sim 10^{-3}$, thus $h=10^{-5}$.

The range $h=0.005$ down to $10^{-5}$ should give correct results. The small steps would appear wasteful where the solution is practically zero, but increasing above the stability constraint $h=0.025$ will magnify the small values to large errors. With explicit method with step size control you get to the stability boundary where the solution is below the absolute error threshold. To get unlimited step size increases you will need implicit methods, be that one-step or multi-step, also with step-size control.